# How to format the beginning a loop correctly?

Tags: python, loops, iteration, dropbox

I have a program which I designed both for myself and my colleague to use, with all the data being stored in a directories. However, I want to set up the loop so that it work both for me and him. I tried all of these:

```
file_location = glob.glob('/../*.nc')
file_location = glob('/../*.nc')
```

But none of them are picking up any files. How can I fix this?

Comment: If you are using 'relative paths' (like `../`) you need to make sure you're running the script from the same 'relative' position on each user's machine.

Comment: Is `epsuser` your user name? What about doing something like `glob.glob(os.path.expanduser('~/Dropbox/Argo/Data/*.nc'))`?

Comment: If you're using relative paths, it'll depend on what your current working directory is when you run the program. Since the absolute path is working fine, it's likely that your current directory isn't beneath "/Users/epsuser". Also, the first two alternatives you tried won't work, the initial "/" means the root directory and there isn't anything above that so both of them are trying "/Dropbox/Argo/Data/*.nc" which doesn't exist.

Comment: What "loop" are you referring to in the title? Did you mean "beginning of a pathname"?

Comment: It'd help to know whether you're trying to access "Dropbox/Argo/Data/*.nc" relative to wherever your current directory is, or are you trying to access it relative to the current user's home directory. Is it perchance the second?

Comment: @ToddKnarr the "Dropbox/Argo/Data/*.nc" is the constant in both of our computers, the beginning is what I am trying to change.

Comment: @jphollowed thank you, that solved it!

Answer (score 4):

You can get a directory relative to a user's home (called `~` in the function call) using [`os.path.expanduser()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser).  In your case, the line would be

```
file_location = glob.glob(os.path.expanduser('~/Dropbox/Argo/Data/*.nc'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually is a good practice not hardcoding paths if you're going to use your paths for other tasks which need well-formed paths (ie: subprocess, writing paths to shell scripts), I'd recommend to manage paths using the `os.path` module instead, for example:

```
import os, glob

home_path = os.path.expanduser("~")
dropbox_path = os.path.join(home_path, "Dropbox")
good_paths = glob.glob(os.path.join(dropbox_path,"Argo","Data","*.nc"))
bad_paths = glob.glob(dropbox_path+"/Argo\\Data/*.nc")

print len(good_paths)==len(bad_paths)
print all([os.path.exists(p) for p in good_paths])
print all([os.path.exists(p) for p in bad_paths])
```

The example shows a comparison between bad and well formed paths. Both of them will work, but good_paths will be more flexible and portable in the long term.

Comment: uglier, but certainly more portable

Comment: @jphollowed Well, the accepted answer would crash on my windows box, so i definitely prefer my "uglier" way ;)

Comment: @BPL what version of windows are you running that doesn't support `/` as a path separator?

Comment: @RoadieRich I've elaborated further my answer. Indeed, `/` will be handled alright by windows... but hardcoded paths can give a lot of headaches depending for which uses